# How to add multiply D3js trees on the same svg path?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

I **want to get 2 trees one is shifted** `o.x += 100` from another tree. 
**But I just get the two trees each under another one**. And has no ideas how to shift another tree to the right.
It could be seen on the snapshot http://screencloud.net/v/1LCD 
(The first tree is already rendered, but another one is in the process)

```
 for root in roots
      new Tree(root, @svg)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4q5ax/

PS For the first tree I use suffix `1` (for the `name`s in `roots` variable) and suffix `2` for another one. Thanks. Sorry for large amont of code.

Comment: You just have to make sure that the two SVGs appear next to each other in CSS. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705804/css-positioning-elements-next-to-each-other) should help with that.

Comment: Is it possible to draw 2 and more trees in one svg canvas (not into 2 divs) ?

Comment: I've appended wrap block  http://jsfiddle.net/4q5ax/2/ `@svg = svg.append("g").attr({"class", "to-float", style: "float: left;"})` but css properties doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use "float" on a `<g>`; if you want both charts in the same SVG, then you have to set their positions explicitly, using a `transform` attribute to move the second `<g>` to the right, and specifying the width of each tree to only be half the width of the svg.