# Placing elements side by side

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an advert listing page where I would like to place the listings side by side-two by two. Is there a ways of doing this with css? At the moment there is just one listing per line. In mobile I'd like two by two, in desktop maybe five or six across.

HTML:

```
<div class="awpcp-listings awpcp-clearboth">
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt displayaditemseven 
    $isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
    [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
      <a class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-listing-link" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
    2/awpcp-show-ad/25/scalf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">. 
    <img class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-thumbnail" 
    alt="Scalf" src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
    content/uploads/awpcp/thumbs/img_
    20190509_111641-fb80c099-primary.jpg" width="80"/>. 
    </a></div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
    inner" style="w">
      <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
    2/awpcp-show- 
    ad/25/scalf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scalf</a></h4>
      <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">A second hand scalf. Grey, warm and good condition.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- extra">
      05/09/2019<br/>London<br/>Price: £ 0.99</div>
    <span class="fixfloat"></span></div>
  <div class="fixfloat"></div>
  <div class="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt displayaditemsodd $isfeaturedclass" data- breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp-listing-excerpt" data- breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": [328,600], "medium": 
    [600,999999]}'>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
    thumbnail">
      <a class="awpcp-listing-primary-image- 
    listing-link" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test- 
    dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/24/the-plumed-serpent-d- 
    h-lawrence/london/uk/barnet/books/"><img class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-thumbnail" alt="The 
    Plumed Serpent - D. H. Lawrence" src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
    content/uploads/awpcp/thumbs/12101950-34ec6e5b- 
    primary.jpg" width="80" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
      <h4 class="awpcp-listing- 
    title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test- 
    dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/24/the-plumed-serpent-d- 
    h-lawrence/london/uk/barnet/books/">The Plumed 
    Serpent - D. H. Lawrence</a></h4>
      <div class="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt-content">Used but readable condition. One of his lesser known works, but nevertheless an intriguing tale of pastorally inspired pagan methodologies&hellip;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
    extra">
      05/08/2019<br/> London
      <br/> Price: £ 0.99
    </div>
    <span class="fixfloat"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="fixfloat"></div>
</div>
<div class="pager">
  <form class="awpcp-pagination-form" method="get">.
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <select name="results">
              <option value="5">5</option>
```

HTML which I have access to modify:

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
    $isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
    [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
  <div class="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt-thumbnail">$awpcp_image_name_srccode
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
    <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
    content">$excerpt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
     extra">$awpcpadpostdate $awpcp_city_display $awpcp_state_display $awpcp_display_adviews $awpcp_display_price $awpcpextrafields
  </div><span class="fixfloat"></span>
</div>
<div class="fixfloat"></div>
```

If there is a modification for second part of html, happy to consider, but perhaps css can determine this? Page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

One of the more challenging issues is that there are so many divs which make up each listing. So, in order to target with css I'd have to do something like. `.awpcp-subtitle, .
.awpcp-show-ad,.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner,.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra,.....`

Comment: This is a very basic CSS question, please do some proper research on the topic in general. A simple google query such as “css get elements next to each other” could have let you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705804/ already, and there are lots more. (If you go with a float-based solution, the `.fixfloat` elements in your HTML are going to be a problem, because they explicitly clear floating, so you would either have to remove those elements, or overwrite the clearing.)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response but, whilst it might seems basic, the SO example you gave doesn't fix my problem, neither does removing `fix-float`

Comment: Well that is probably due to the fact that your actual problem rather is the lack of knowledge concerning some CSS basic concepts to begin with … and IMHO it should not be the purpose of this site to explain those over and over again to every single newbie that wanders in here - that’s what beginner tutorials are for.

Comment: Add `width: 50%; float: left;` to the elements with the class `awpcp-listing-excerpt` - and take it from there. Manipulate the width using your browser dev tools, and see how that changes things. Need more than that - then it really is time that you go read up on stuff a bit first.

Comment: You're probably right, I don't have the brain for these type of things you see so it takes me twice as long as others... :-)

Comment: That kinda worked you know.... you're a genius dude, not perfect but good start, very good start. So what now? :-) https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Try below code.

```css
*
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.advertise_container
{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.advertise
{
flex:100%;
padding:10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:576px)
{
.advertise
{
      flex:50%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
{
.advertise
{
      flex:33.33%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:992px)
{
.advertise
{
      flex:25%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="advertise_container">
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
<div class="advertise">
oneeeee
</div>
</div>
```