# How to have two photos next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS and I want to have 2 photos next to each other. Unfortunately, the second photo is below the first photo.

```css
.container{
 width:80px;
 margin:0 auto;
 justify-content:center;
 display:flex; 
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="card_img"></img>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="card_img"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put the images in the same `container`?

Comment: As a sidenote: `img` cannot have a closing tag `</img>`. Either leave it out, or use self-closing syntax: `<img src="foo.jpg" />`. Also you have one `</div>` too much. Lastly, your first `div` has the class `containers`. In your second div (and in the CSS you show) you're using `container`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Ok, my stupid fault, thanks

Comment: It is worth noting that the first image container class doesn't match the css, with the extra "s". Also, `<img>` tags are self closing, therefore they don't need the unnecessary closing tags `</img>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Positioning Elements Next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705804/css-positioning-elements-next-to-each-other)

Comment: look up flexbox and do a column.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this code, hope it will work for you. max-height of image is just for the display image as small size.

```css
.container{display: flex;display: -webkit-flex;justify-content: center;}
.container img { max-height: 150px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg" class="card_img" />
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg" class="card_img" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your first div has the class "containers" instead of "container". You should give both the same classname.

You could also add "float: left" to your css like this to show your images side by side:

```
.container {
    width:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    justify-content:center;
    display:flex;   
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not perfectly clear about your question. But if you mean the div's to align side by side. you can use justify-content: flex-start in your class.

```
.container{
    width:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    display:flex;   
}
```

You will have to change your html:

```
<div class="container">
<div><img src="photo1.jpg" class="card_img" /></div>
<div><img src="photo1.jpg" class="card_img" /></div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use flexbox, you can use float:left. I prefer flexbox though.

Comment: OK, my photos are each other, but don't centre horizontally