# Is it possible to reduce space around shinyWidgets radioGroupButtons and shiny fileInput?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets, bslib

Is it possible to adjust space around specific instances of `radioGroupButtons` and `fileInput`?

For example, how could the fileInput1 and radioGroupButtons1 be made stacked one on top of the other?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

# UI
ui = page_fillable(
  fileInput("fileInput1", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons1", choices = c("TSV", "CSV", "XLSX")),
  
  fileInput("fileInput2", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons2", choices = c("PDF", "PNG", "JPEG"))
)

# Server
server = function(input, output, session)
{
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: To reduce the space between any two elements, you can insert a `div` with a negative height between these two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smartse reminded me there is a progress bar at the bottom of the `fileInput` element. The arrangement I was looking for can be achieved by adjusting its `margin`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

# UI
ui = page_fillable(

  # Adjust margin of progress bar
  tags$style("#fileInput1_progress { margin: -24px; }"),

  fileInput("fileInput1", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons1", choices = c("TSV", "CSV", "XLSX")),
  
  fileInput("fileInput2", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons2", choices = c("PDF", "PNG", "JPEG"))
)

# Server
server = function(input, output, session)
{
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean. It could maybe do with more tweaking to adjust the whitespace between them too but the progress bar shows up beneath when the file is uploaded.

```
ui = page_fillable(
  tags$head(
  tags$style(type="text/css", 
       ".radio_style .form-group {float:left; display:inline; width: 300px;}")),
  div(class='radio_style', 
  fileInput("fileInput1", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons1", choices = c("TSV", "CSV", "XLSX"))
  ),
  div(class='radio_style', 
  fileInput("fileInput2", label = NULL),
  radioGroupButtons("radioGroupButtons2", choices = c("PDF", "PNG", "JPEG"))
  )
)
```

[image]

Credit to [CSS Positioning Elements Next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705804/css-positioning-elements-next-to-each-other)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, smartse. Sorry for the ambiguous phrasing - I would like them one on top of the other rather than side-by-side. I edited the questions to make it clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean - maybe create an image showing what you want?

Comment: I added an answer with an example showing what I wanted.